# How to give rows and column header to a list output from loop in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, header

I have a small loop which gives me list of data for n number of segments. Below is the code:

```
for df_grp in df.groupby(['Segment']):
  grp_ci = 1.96 * np.std(grp['Conversion_Percentage'])/math.sqrt(len(grp['Conversion_Percentage']))
  grp_cvr = grp['Conversion_Percentage'].iloc[-1]
  grp_ci95plus = grp_cvr + grp_ci
  grp_ci95minus = grp_cvr - grp_ci
  stat = (grp_ci,grp_cvr,grp_ci95plus,grp_ci95minus)
  print(stat)
```

I basically want these 4 statistical outputs which I am getting here as a list which is shown below:

```
(0.7443617976588611, 8.349514563106796, 9.093876360765657, 7.605152765447935)
(0.5279035518807871, 7.9468622035996574, 8.474765755480444, 7.418958651718871)
```

Here is the sample data groupbed by segment A, similarly for other segments. This particular subsets give the 4 stat values that I am calculating:

```
                 days       user      Conversion_Percentage
0                0.0        618               2.942577
1                1.0        638               3.037806
2                2.0        662               3.152081
3                3.0        686               3.266356
4                4.0        726               3.456814
5                5.0        835               3.975812
6                6.0        915               4.356728
7                7.0        971               4.623369
8                8.0       1004               4.780497
```

But instead I want this to come in a tabular form. And most importantly I want to get row and column headers. I tried converting the list to dataframe:

```
  array = (grp_ci,grp_cvr,grp_ci95plus,grp_ci95minus)
  index_values = ['grp']
  column_values = ['ci','cvr','ci95plus','ci95minus']
  stat= pd.DataFrame(data = array, index = index_values, columns = column_values)
  print(stat)
```

But it gave me the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'
```

I have already checked that I do not have named any file or script using the package names but still could not understand this error. I also changed my dataframe code many times to see if I am writing the code wrong but no luck. My grp which is segment is something that I want in row and as the 4 stats are calculated I want them in column header. Better if it is in tabulated form but at least I need headers. This will be better if I have a lot of segment values and I will have all my segments printed in each row of the 4 columns. Something like this:

```
      ci                  cvr                   ci95plus                    ci95minus
  
A     0.7443617976588611  8.349514563106796     9.093876360765657           7.605152765447935

B     0.5279035518807871  7.9468622035996574    8.474765755480444           7.418958651718871
```

**Edit: I changed Dataframe to DataFrame. Apologies for that. Now I am getting the error:**
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 1), indices imply (1, 4)

Comment: pd.Dataframe -> pd.DataFrame

Comment: @JASONGPETERSON Sorry for that mistake. I just corrected it. Still getting the error ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 1), indices imply (1, 4)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are working with a list. You can try this.

```
import pandas
import numpy

DATA = {'days': [0.0 ,1.0 ,2.0 ,3.0 ,4.0 ,5.0 ,6.0 ,7.0 ,8.0],
       'user': [618 ,638 ,662 ,686 ,726 ,835 ,915 ,971 ,1004],
        'Conversion_Percentage': [2.942577 ,3.037806 ,3.152081 
        ,3.266356 ,3.456814 ,3.975812 ,4.356728 ,4.623369 ,4.780497]}

# You need to adjust the calculation in the function to suit what you want to achieve.
def conversion(x):
    grp_cvr= 1.96 * np.std(df['Conversion_Percentage'])/math.sqrt(len(df['Conversion_Percentage']))
    grp_ci= x  #adjust to fit your calculation
    grp_ci95plus = grp_cvr + grp_ci
    grp_ci95minus = grp_cvr - grp_ci    
    return grp_ci,grp_cvr,grp_ci95plus,grp_ci95minus


#columns and index mapping
index2 = {0: 'A', 1: 'b', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G', 7: 'H', 8: 'I'}

col= ['ci','cvr','ci95plus','ci95minus']

new_columns=dict(zip(range(len(col)),col))


df= pd.DataFrame(DATA)
new =(df['Conversion_Percentage'].apply(conversion)
             .apply(pd.Series))
            

index2 = {0: 'A', 1: 'b', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G', 7: 'H', 8: 'I'}
new_columns=dict(zip(new.columns,['ci','cvr','ci95plus','ci95minus']))

new.columns=new_columns
```

Comment: I do not want to input those values in the data_a. They are rather outcome of my operation what I am doing in loop. If I have six segments lest say A to F then I will have same 4 columns and six rows A to F

Comment: Well that should be pretty easy as well. You can save them into a dictionary. I cant really visualize what you intend to do without sharing sample data. Besides, why are you looping. wont the apply method be better suited?

Comment: How do I save them into a dictionary? I have a segment column and one numeric column through which I am calculating those 4 statistical metric.

Comment: you can use defaultdict(list). But i still think an apply method would be better suited for what you are trying to do. Can you provide a replicable sample data?

Comment: I have readjusted the code inline with your new data provided. you could tweak it to suit your calculation

Comment: It is still not working. What is the index2 doing? I could not understand that. I mean I need my rows of that table to be the number of segments I have I mean the number of times my loop is running. This creates more than that with A B C D as the row headers.

Comment: what is not working, the index or the whole solution?

Comment: I think it is index that is causing the problem. I changed it to Index2 = {0:key} because I do not want many rows I want one row per key but still not what I want. It looks like its over complicating the output.

Comment: just ignore the index argument. by default the index would be arranged by order of creation. that in it self should solve it

Comment: I did that and also removed it from the rename line of the code. Still not working

Comment: is you issue with the index?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236523/discussion-between-abhishek-singh-and-ade-1).